# Large size of Bool in Foreign.Storable

Tags: haskell, memory

I see:

```
GHCi> import Foreign.Storable
GHCi> sizeOf False
4
```

I expected it to be 1. But I thought it perhaps carries some pointer or something that forces it to be bigger. But it does not seem to be necessary:

```
GHCi> import Data.Word
GHCi> sizeOf (0 :: Word8)
1
```

What is it that forces `Bool` to be stored this big? It seems like a huge waste of memory.

Comment: I suspect this is because `Bool` is a boxed type.

Comment: Maybe it because traditionally boolean type in C is int.

Comment: And really you need a bit to store boolean value, so a byte is big too.

Comment: Even in C99 there's a `_Bool` type whose size is >=1. New GCCs define that as 1, but pre-C99 GCCs defined `typedef int _Bool`, making it whatever `sizeof(int)` is on your system, 4 is common.

Comment: @freestyle re “a byte is big too” – the C++ Standard Template Library found it a good idea to [“optimise” vectors of bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) for this reason, so each element would asymptotically only take up one bit. This turned out to be a major headache in many applications and is now widely considered to have been a bad idea. (I reckon it would be less problematic in Haskell, though, but then, we don't like booleans very much anyway, so...)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't know exactly why in C++ the vector of `Bool` led to the problem, but I assume that this is because the interface assumed the possibility of addressing (by the pointer or C++ reference) the element of the vector, which is not possible in a simple way if elements stored as bit sequence. But in Haskell we addressing to element by it index and I believe we can represent `vector Bool` as bit sequence. But is it necessary? I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with GHC-8.2/base-4.10, there is the type `CBool` that only needs one byte when stored via `Storable`.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Foreign-C-Types.html#t:CBool

Alternatively, there is the new package `bool8`. It provides a wrapper type around `Bool` and its `Storable` instance uses only one byte.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bool8

Answer (score 1):

From the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Foreign.Storable.html#Storable), we have:

```
instance Storable Bool where
   sizeOf _ = sizeOf (undefined::HTYPE_INT)
```

And `HTYPE_INT` is defined in [HsBaseConfig.h](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/src/include/HsBaseConfig.h) as:

```
/* Define to Haskell type for int */
#define HTYPE_INT Int32
```

This could give you the result 4, although I believe this value should be implementation-specific.

Comment: I winder why that was chosen, though, when `char` would have been fine for that.

Comment: @chi Yeah, I've been trying to check if there's anything in the mailing lists/other places about the choice

Comment: So maybe I could rephrase the orignal question to: Why it's not `sizeOf _ = sizeOf (undefined::HTYPE_CHAR)`?

Comment: In which case, I suppose you would need to contact the creators (not sure if they are on SO)